# Ruby - hashes, symbols and strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I have gem that returns next hash object

```
{:response=>"There was an error authenticating the sender account.", :status_code=>401}
```

and in my rake task i'm trying to access it's properties:

```
response = my_gem.execute
puts response
puts response.has_key?(:respose)
puts response[:respose]
```

But i can't understand why it prints

```
{:response=>"There was an error authenticating the sender account.", :status_code=>401}
false
```

Why can't i access :response property with response[:respose] ?

P.S. response[response.keys.first] works but it's very weird solution

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo/syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in the below :

```
puts response.has_key?(:respose)
```

`has_key?(:respose)` should be `has_key?(:response)`.

```
response = {:response=>"There was an error authenticating the sender account.", :status_code=>401}
response.has_key?(:response)
# => true
```

Comment: yep, long working day... :(

Comment: @Olexandr It happens I know... take some rest and teat :))